# Parse Error: Cyclic Dependency in App Initializer

Tags: angular6, cyclic-dependency

I am implementing app initializer and I came across cyclic dependency error as below

> Uncaught Error: Provider parse errors:
>   Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! ApplicationRef ("[ERROR ->]"): in NgModule AppModule in ./AppModule@-1:-1
>       at NgModuleProviderAnalyzer.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.NgModuleProviderAnalyzer.parse (compiler.js:11472)
>       at NgModuleCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.NgModuleCompiler.compile (compiler.js:11836)
>       at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModule (compiler.js:23882)
>       at compiler.js:23841
>       at Object.then (compiler.js:1007)
>       at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:23839)
>       at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (compiler.js:23799)
>       at CompilerImpl.push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/fesm5/platform-browser-dynamic.js.CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync (platform-browser-dynamic.js:143)
>       at PlatformRef.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (core.js:4352)
>       at Object../src/main.ts (main.ts:11)
>   push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.NgModuleProviderAnalyzer.parse @ compiler.js:11472
>   push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.NgModuleCompiler.compile @ compiler.js:11836
>   push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModule @ compiler.js:23882
>   (anonymous) @ compiler.js:23841
>   then @ compiler.js:1007
>   push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents @ compiler.js:23839
>   push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync @ compiler.js:23799
>   push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/fesm5/platform-browser-dynamic.js.CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync @ platform-browser-dynamic.js:143
>   push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.PlatformRef.bootstrapModule @ core.js:4352
>   ./src/main.ts @ main.ts:11
>   **webpack_require** @ bootstrap:81
>   0 @ main.ts:12
>   **webpack_require** @ bootstrap:81
>   checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:43
>   webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:30
>   (anonymous) @ main.js:1

This is how my initializer looks like

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class InitializerService {

    
    flag = false;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

    initialize(): boolean {
        // access query params using ActivatedRoute object
        // some http calls using HttpClient object
        // also use objects of HttpHeaders and HttpParams
        return this.flag;
    }
}
```

Below is how I am providing the service in NgModule

```js
providers: [
    InitializerService,
    { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: init_app, deps: [InitializerService], multi: true},
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: Interceptor, multi: true }
  ],
```

I am not sure why do I see the cyclic dependency error

Answer (score -1):

ActivatedRoute isn't available at APP_INITIALIZER due to bootstrapping. You can use the APP_BOOTSTRAP_LISTENER InjectionToken to make sure the ActivatedRoute is available (which occurs after the bootstrapping is finished).